# Database query is not updating

Tags: php, mysql

My database is not updating when I click the submit button.

Here is the code (I already have the database connection code):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$product_add=$_POST['product_add'];
$add_item=$_POST['add_item'];

$get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stock WHERE item='$product_add'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($get);

$qty_left = $row['qty_left'];
$qty = $add_item + $qty_left;

mysql_query("UPDATE stock SET qty_left='$qty' WHERE item='$product_add'") or        die(mysql_error());
}


?>
```

Comment: What does mysql_error() say?

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ). **You are also wide open to [SQL injections](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174)**

Comment: Is your submit button named? I.e.: `name="submit"` and all form elements are indeed named? If your submit button isn't named, nothing will happen because everything first revolves around that conditional statement. Show your HTML form to be certain. `name="Submit"` and `name="submit"` are **two different animals** altogether. `A!=a;`

Comment: I see no syntax error (excluding your table column names of course), so I guess either your `if` condition is not getting executed or your `where` clause in the update statement isn't matching any rows

Comment: Also, if your DB connection is `mysqli_*` based, then another reason why your query will fail. If your DB is `mysqli_*`, then that function and `mysql_*` functions do not mix together. Show full code. There are too many things that can go wrong, and I mean **TOO many.**

Comment: @JohnCode where can i see that?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, my submit button named name="submit"

Comment: @asprin i don't have any if conditions but i have a row named item

Comment: <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
    <h3 align="center">Product Name</h3>
    <?php
  include("database_connect.php");
  session_start();
   
  $select_query = "SELECT item FROM stock";
  $select_query_run = mysql_query($select_query);
  echo "<select name='product_add' class='form-control'>";
  while ($select_query_array=   mysql_fetch_array($select_query_run) )
  {
   echo "<option value='' >".htmlspecialchars($select_query_array["item"])."</option>";
  }
  
  echo "</select><br>";
 ?>

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="add_item" placeholder="Number of item to add"><br><br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Add</button>
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  {
   $product_add=$_POST['product_add'];
   $add_item=$_POST['add_item'];
   
   $get = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stock WHERE item='$product_add'");
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($get);
   
   $qty_left = $row['qty_left'];
   $qty = $add_item + $qty_left;
   
   mysql_query("UPDATE stock SET qty_left='$qty' WHERE item='$product_add'") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
</form>

Comment: @Fred-ii- here is the DB Connection

mysql_connect('localhost', 'root') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('dbproject') or die(mysql_error());

Comment: it is required for us to use mysql functions

Comment: @user3501563 - could you edit that into your question?

Comment: Consult my answer below @user3501563

Comment: (Once you've edited those updates into your question, please delete the comments to keep the question clear for future readers. Thanks)

Answer (score 1):

So many possible reasons:

1. Is the update query being executed at all? In other way, is `isset($_POST['submit'])` true ? (in addition to the `type` attribute, you should have the `name="submit"` in the submit button for it to work. Unless one of your fields' name is actually "submit" which I doubt)
2. Is your connection working? `var_dump($row);` should answer your question
3. There's a config variable called autocommit normally set to 1. If not, you would have to `mysql_query('COMMIT');` everytime you want to save changes to the database. Try adding `mysql_query('SET autocommit=1');` ... who knows?

Also, always escape/cast your variables! And also you can get rid of the first query.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $product_add = addslashes($_POST['product_add']);
    $add_item    = (int)$_POST['add_item'];

    mysql_query("UPDATE stock SET qty_left = qty_left + $add_item 
                 WHERE item='$product_add'") 
            or die(mysql_error());
}    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to var_dump your query and execute it on phpMyAdmin: if it works, probably your mysql_connect has wrong access data

Answer (score 0):

As per what you left for (form-related) code [`in a comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883260/database-query-is-not-updating/22883852#comment34918358_22883260)

In your `echo "<select name='product_add' class='form-control'>";` you need to add `type="text"`.

Change it to:

```
echo "<select name='product_add' type="text" class='form-control'>";
```

This will affect your query.